# Resolve dependency issue for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've downloaded a sample solution and it has dependency issues, when I check the nuget manager, I don't see any option to update/install it and it shows already installed. How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Actually build the project, look in the Output window for any warnings.  I get some too, analyzer problems, the VS integration hasn't been very good.  Keeping VS updated is important, do mention your version number as visible in Help > About.

Comment: The version is 15.9.11 Visual Studio 2017 https://i.imgur.com/0NtOnqb.png and when I build/rebuild, I'm getting errors: https://i.imgur.com/m8hD6fZ.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, had to remove the `telerik.ui.forasp.netcore` from the Nuget, then every dependency cleared as available. Then just had to find `telerik.ui.for.aspnet.core` and install and it worked.